# Change a column_vector to a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matrix

I have a column vector that needs to be changed into a matrix.  The size of matrix is specified and can change.  Please suggest a vectorized solution.

```
rows = 3 ; cols = 4 ; %matrix elements for this case = 12

colvector = [ 2;4;5;8;10;14;16;18;20;21;28;30] ;

desired_mat = [ ...
               2     4     5     8
              10    14    16    18
              20    21    28    30 ] ;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) function does that:

```
>> colvector = [ 2;4;5;8;10;14;16;18;20;21;28;30] ;
>> A = reshape(colvector, 3, 4)

A =

     2     8    16    21
     4    10    18    28
     5    14    20    30
```